# Executor Service - timeout of thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

While I was exploring `ExecutorService`, I encountered a method `Future.get()` which accepts the `timeout`.

The Java doc of this method says

---

Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.

Parameters:

**timeout** the maximum time to wait

**unit** the time unit of the timeout argument

---

As per my understanding, we are imposing a timeout on the `callable`, we submit to the `ExecutorService` so that, my `callable` will **interrupt** after the specified time(timeout) has passed

But as per below code, the `longMethod()` seems to be running beyond the timeout(2 seconds), and I am really confused understanding this. Can anyone please point me to the right path?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Timeout implements Callable<String> {

    public void longMethod() {
        for(int i=0; i< Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        longMethod();
        return "done";
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        try {
            service.submit(new Timeout()).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers, note that even if the task was interrupted, since it never checks the interrupt flag anyway, it would continue to run until the end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*my callable will interrupt after the specified time(timeout) has passed*

Not true. The task will continue to execute, instead you will have a null string after the timeout.

If you want to cancel it:

```
  timeout.cancel(true) //Timeout timeout = new Timeout();
```

P.S. As you have it right now this interrupt will have no effect what so ever. You are not checking it in any way.

For example this code takes into account interrupts:

```
    private static final class MyCallable implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;++i){
                builder.append("a");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread was interrupted");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable();
    Future<String> futureResult = service.submit(myCallable);
    String result = null;
    try{
        result = futureResult.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }catch(TimeoutException e){
        System.out.println("No response after one second");
        futureResult.cancel(true);
    }
    service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Within your Callable use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() (or Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) to check if Future.cancel has been called.  If your Callables are not long running this may not be necessary but for long running Callables this will allow you to cleanly shutdown the thread if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The timeout on get() is for how long the 'client' will wait for the Future to complete. It does not have an impact on the future's execution.

```
Object result;
int seconds = 0;
while ((result = fut.get.(1, TimeUnit.SECOND)) == null) {
    seconds++;
    System.out.println("Waited " + seconds + " seconds for future";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my callable will **interrupt** after the specified time(timeout) has passed

The above statement is wrong, Usually Future.get is blocking. Specifying the timeout allows you to use it in a non blocking manner.

This is useful for instance in time critical applications, if you need a result within let's say 2 seconds and receiving after that means you can't do anything with that.